# Localizing/Scoping a sass mixin

Tags: css, sass

Is there a way to localize a SCSS mixin to apply only to a certain scope?

I have the following [example](http://codepen.io/ColdToast/pen/urtkx)

... where I have a couple basic mixins

```
@mixin shadow ($color) { 
  text-shadow: 4px 3px 0 $color, 7px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

@mixin shadow-icon ($color) { 
  span[class*='entypo'] {
    @include shadow($color);
    font-size: 156px;
  }  
}
```

I dont want to repeat the exact same code for every `item` with just a different color. But this will be a one off style for this page so I dont want these to be accessible from anywhere just this file/scope/etc.

Does there exist a way to localize or scope a mixin?

Comment: Why is it a problem that the mixin is in the global scope exactly?

Comment: Because I dont want it used outside of this scope and I wouldnt want to overwrite a different mixin with the same name. This is a rather large project with many ppl working on it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured it out. Mixins use the same rules as sass variables in that if they are nested inside a block of code its not viewable/useable outside that block.

So for this what I did was just nest the different "items" inside the `item` definition; define the mixin inside the `item` definition. And the result is that the mixin can only be used within that `item` block.

[Check it out](http://codepen.io/ColdToast/pen/urtkx)

```
.item {
  @mixin shadow-icon ($color) { 
    span[class*='entypo'] {
      text-shadow: 4px 3px 0 $color, 7px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
      font-size: 156px;
    }  
  }

  &.create {
    $createColor: rgb(69, 178, 157);

    background: $createColor;

    @include shadow-icon($createColor);
  }

  &.view {
    $viewColor: rgb(239, 201, 76);

    background: $viewColor;

    @include shadow-icon($viewColor);
  }

  &.report {
    $reportColor: rgb(226, 122, 63);

    background: $reportColor;

    @include shadow-icon($reportColor);
  }
}
```